# What does Oracle SYSDATE - 1/8 mean?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sysdate

I am looking at a query:

```
select JOB_ID from db where last_updated_date >= sysdate - 1/8
```

I went through the `ORACLE` `SYSDATE` documentation but couldn't understand what `sysdate - 1/8` means.

Please clarify.

Comment: it's subtracting 3 hours

Comment: This expression has nothing about `sysdate`, you need to check [datetime/interval arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, it means you're subtracting 1/8 of the whole day. As one day has 24 hours, its 1/8th part is 24/8 = 3 hours. So:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate col1,
  2         sysdate - 1/8 col2
  3  from dual;

COL1                COL2
------------------- -------------------
29.10.2021 22:18:36 29.10.2021 19:18:36

SQL>
```

- date value remained the same (it is still today, 29.10.2021)
- time has changed; right now, it is 22:18:36. When we subtract 3 hours from it, we get 19:18:36 (3 hours earlier)

It means that your query fetches rows whose `last_updated_date` column value is within the last 3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

It will subtract 3 hours (24 hours/8) from `sysdate`, try running the following:

```
select to_char((sysdate - 1/8), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual
```

This will give you 3 hours previous to the current date/time of the database.